# How does an Angular 2 and .Net Core 2.0 app interact with each other and the development cycle, in general?

Tags: c#, sql, angular, deployment, .net-core

I'm a pretty new developer and want to improve my skills in three specific technologies, C#/.Net, Angular 2, and SQL. To that end, I'm creating an app using those technologies. I'm using Visual Studio Community Edition which gives an option for Angular 2 to be integrated into the creation of the template.

My question is this, in Angular, in my limited experience, most of the logic seems to be written in the services.ts or component.ts files.

- When would I need to write code in C#?
- Wouldn't all my code by written in TypeScript on the Angular side?
- What is the purpose of connecting Angular to .Net Core in the first place?
- Does this mean that I'm no longer running an MVC project? How does that affect my development?
- Will I be allowed/required/encouraged to use an ORM such as Entity Framework on this project?
- How will deployment be affected? (I really have very little experience with deployment at the moment, TBH).

**EDIT**
To clarify, I've made several projects using the MEAN stack (Mongoose, Express, Angular2, Node.js) together with MongoDB as well as C# projects using .Net Core with PostgreSQL, Entity Framework Core, and the Razor View Engine.

So, I know how to make them separately, I just don't understand how they work together.

Comment: Asp.Net Core would replace the Node.js (server) part of your stack, and you wouldn't use Razor views, instead setting up the server like an API that just passes data to the Angular part of the app.

Comment: You might need to install [this template](https://dotnetnew.azurewebsites.net/pack/Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates) first (or maybe not, I don't remember)... but then the simple command `dotnet new angular` will scaffold you a lovely, well architected, idiomatic skeleton app that shows you pretty much exactly what to do and where to do it. Have an explore.

Comment: @MBaka, when you choose using Angular + .NET Core 2.0 the general idea is that .NET is using only to serve the data (you have services .NET that return Json). In Startup.cs you configure the routes to say that all the url thats begans with "/api" return "data" and the rest call to Index.html. There are a good series (incompleted) in https://code-maze.com/net-core-series/ to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple, you use .net core to create a backend web service / API, this can be REST based, GraphQL, or in any other format that you would like.

You then build your front end in angular and it communicates with the .net core server side through the protocol that you choose previously (GraphQL,REST, etc).

The answers to your specific questions vary based on the kind of project.
I will answer them in context of a simple TO-DO list application.

- When would I need to write code in C#?

You would write the server side code in C#, meaning the code that receives the data for the TO-DO items and stores it and the code that returns the TO-DO items to the client.

- Wouldn't all my code by written in TypeScript on the Angular side?

Yes, all of your client-side code can be written in Angular and TypeScript

- What is the purpose of connecting Angular to .Net Core in the first place?

So that your TO-DO app will be able to function on any device and will be able to retrieve and add list items from anywhere.

- Does this mean that I'm no longer running an MVC project? How does that affect my development?

Absolutely not, Your application can still be MVC, the only difference between using .net core is that you will be populating the model with data from the server now instead of storing it somewhere locally when using just Angular

- Will I be allowed/required/encouraged to use an ORM such as Entity Framework on this project?

There are no requirements as to whether to use an ORM at all or which one to use when building with .net core. That said I would highly reccomend Entity Framework core as it makes working with databases a cinch.

- How will deployment be affected? (I really have very little experience with deployment at the moment, TBH).

You will now have to deploy two applications, one a server side .net core application and one client side SPA built in angular.

Comment: Thanks for the well constructed answer!